# Framing bits with matlab

Tags: matlab, encoding, decoding, bit

Please 
How I can make framing process for data bits .
Moreover, deframing with serializing the data. Finally, sending data  to BSC BINARY symmetric channel.

Comment: Communications System Toolbox